# What's the best use of the [agi] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question that was meant to discuss artificial intelligence in general. I tagged it [artificial-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), and someone fairly pointed out that that's redundant. I changed it to [agi](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agi), because the question referred specifically to how [optimization](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) applies to artificial intelligence, but I'm not sure that was right.

Should the [agi](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agi) tag refer only to questions that reference Artificial General Intelligence specifically, or can it be used for questions that could be related to AGI in more indirect ways?

Comment: And by the way, is AGI different than or the same as "Strong AI"? If they're the same, which one is preferred? Should we exclude one of the two tags?

Answer (score 2):

[artificial-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) is what SE calls an **intrinsic** tag, as is [ai](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai).

Intrinsic tags are effectively pointless tags on a site, ie this site is about artificial intelligence, so does not need a tag on artificial intelligence. Likewise, [programming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) is not needed on Programming.SE

[optimization](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) is much more relevant, as it is a specific class of questions within the site scope.

Comment: I'm asking about the [tag:agi] tag, not the intrinsic tag.

Answer (score 2):

AGI stands for Artificial General Intelligence, which is an AI that's powerful enough to be applied in general. A human would be an AGI, so to say - the human is generally applicable. So when your question is about such an AI - one that is not made for one specific task, but instead for things in general - where you'd need an AI that can think and learn as it goes - to deal with moving goalposts - that's the sort of question you'd use [agi](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agi) for.